# WordPress Excerpt Doesn't Format Link Correctly

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress Avada theme and try to modify the 'Read more' link to always go to an external site.

I'm using the following code :

```
function my_read_more_link( $read_more ) {
    $post = get_post();
    $url = 'https:/www.websitename.com/';
    $postslug = $post->post_name;
    $link = $url . $postslug;
    $excerpt = '<a href="'.$link.'">Read more at websitename.com!</a>';

    return $excerpt;
}
add_filter( 'avada_blog_read_more_link', 'my_read_more_link' );
```

In Theory this is working because the blog page shows the following:

```
<a href="https:/www.websitename.com/the-post-title-here">
    Read more at websitename.com!
</a>
```

But this is formatted as text, not as a link. I've provided some screenshots for more clarity :

Screenshot from the blog page
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvgBD.jpg

Screenshot from the source code : (output) 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4RNN.jpg

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `avada_blog_read_more_link` hook only changes the link text, not the link HTML.

Comment: Many people here do not have access to Avada, since it is a paying theme. It is therefore difficult to help you. I suggest you contact theme-fusion support and ask them which hook to use. Feel free to come back here to publish the solution.

Comment: Check what the theme is using close to where this filter gets applied, to determine the value of the link itself. (Since this is a paid theme, you should probably not post larger code excerpts here.) Maybe a general WP hook such as `the_content_more_link` or `the_permalink` can help you out, if the theme uses default functionality to determine the URL for that link. If that doesn’t help, then as @Robin suggested, contact the theme developers support.

Comment: @Jainil you know what hook changes the html as well?

Comment: @Mand Don't think there is one for that. But you can contact the theme support, they can guide you regarding that.